# How do I get a specific set of data displayed when I check a checkbox component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a table and the table has a column called status. Basically, this status can be in progress, pending or dispensed.

[image: This is the table view]

So what I need to do now is when I check one of the checkboxes that are above the table, I should get only the data related to the checkbox that was checked. For an example if I check the "pending" checkbox, only the data with the pending status should be displayed in the table. Below is a snippet of my checkboxes.

```js
<Grid  container direction="row" justify="space-between">
    <Grid align="left" direction="column" >
        <FormControlLabel
            value="all"
            control={<Checkbox name="all" id="all" color="primary" checked={this.state.checked}/>}
            label="All"
            labelPlacement="end"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
            value="pending"
            control={<Checkbox name="pending" id="pending" color="primary" checked={this.state.showPending}/>}
            label="Pending"
            labelPlacement="end"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
            value="in progress"
            control={<Checkbox name="inProgress" id="inProgress" color="primary" />}
            label="In Progress"
            labelPlacement="end"
        />
        <FormControlLabel
            value="dispensed"
            control={<Checkbox name="dispensed" id="dispensed" color="primary" />}
            label="Dispensed"
            labelPlacement="end"
        />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Currently I'm getting hard coded table data from a json file that I've created.

```js
<Grid container  direction="row">
    {patient.STATUS==="In Progress" && <img src={require("../../../../assets/images/icons/inprogress.svg")} alt="in_progress"  className="pharmacy-dashboard-status-icon-in-progress"/>}
    {patient.STATUS==="Pending" && <img src={require("../../../../assets/images/icons/pending.svg")} alt="pending"  className="pharmacy-dashboard-status-icon-pending"/>}
    {patient.STATUS==="Dispensed" && <img src={require("../../../../assets/images/icons/dispensed.svg")} alt="dispensed"  className="pharmacy-dashboard-status-icon-dispensed"/>}
</Grid>
```

How do I get that specific data to display when I check one of the checkboxes?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach:

1. Create a checkbox event handler and pass the event in it as its parameter
2. By using that parameter you can get following information and data:

   event.target.name // name of the checkbox
   event.target.checked // whether it is checked or not

Create a variable and initialize it with a blank array like:

```
let filteredRecords = [];
```

and on every check/uncheck event `push/pop` the filtered data in that variable and use that variable to render the data with conditional rendering like:

```
{
  ( filteredRecords.length > 0 )
  ?
  // Render the filteredRecords using filteredRecords.map() or something else
  :
  // Render all the records
}
```